# Why save hash history when navigating across different sections on a single page app?

Tags: reactjs

Looking to gain some knowledge about hash history and navigating across a single page React App.

So I have links that take the user to different sections of the app. I then became curious about saving the history as I navigate through the app. I can see why saving the history would be necessary if you want to navigate to different pages of the app, but is it necessary/beneficial to save the history when you navigate through different sections on a single page?

My code would look something like this. I'd have links that will go to a section, which would then update the url.

index.js

```
const history = createHistory()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={App}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return(
          <div>
              <a href="#section1">Section 1 </a>
              <a href="#section1">Section 2 </a>
              <a href="#section1">Section 3 </a>
              <section id="section1></section>
              <section id="section2></section>
              <section id="section3></section>
          </div>
      )
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Basically, how far do you want the user to have ability to share/bookmark?

If you change the location (add to history) for any state of the page, you should be ready to bring the application to that particular state from the location information alone (when the user refreshes the page, or shares the link).

Changing the location without this ability is useless -- for you to code and especially for the user.

This generally means that only major page changes are pushed into history.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary to save `history` when navigating within the same page. `history` is used by `React Router` to match `routes`and to render the components on those `routes`. Since you'll be within the same page/component the `route` will remain the same.